# Accessing data from sqldatereader within a function

Tags: asp.net

I want to output some data to the user based on their username. This data is held in a table that is linked to the aspnet_Users table.  I'm trying to write a sqldatareader as part of a function so I don't have to rewrite the code when it could be called from several pages.  I know this is probably very simple buty I can't seem to access the data from outside the function. The function I have so far is as follows:

```
Public Shared Function AgencyDetails() As SqlDataReader
    Dim details As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Relationships WHERE ContactSub = @Username"
    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ApplicationServices").ConnectionString

    Using dbConnection As New SqlConnection(connString)
        dbConnection.Open()
        Dim cmdAgency As New SqlCommand(details, dbConnection)
        cmdAgency.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", membership.getuser)
        Return cmdAgency.ExecuteReader()


    End Using
End Function
```

How can I call this function and access the information on my page? Something like the following?

```
lblAgencyDetails.text = AgencyDetails(0)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it now, it won't work because you enclosed the connection in a `using` statement, by the time you return the `Reader` the connection will be closed and disposed so the reader won't be able to read anything.

What you should do in that function is load the info in a `DataTable` and return the datatable.

Example:

```
Public Shared Function AgencyDetails() As DataTable
    Dim details As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Relationships WHERE ContactSub = @Username"
    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ApplicationServices").ConnectionString

    Using dbConnection As New SqlConnection(connString)
        dbConnection.Open()
        Dim cmdAgency As New SqlCommand(details, dbConnection)
        cmdAgency.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", membership.getuser)
        Dim dt as new DataTable()
        dt.Load(cmdAgency.ExecuteReader())
        return dt

    End Using
End Function
```

You can access the rows in the data table by doing:

```
For Each row as DataRow in dt.Rows
   Console.WriteLine(row("ColumnName"))
Next
```

Comment: How do I output results from this into my aspx page?

Comment: @ajguk check my update. "ColumnName" is supposed to be the name of one of the columns returned on your select statement. BTW, you should avoid doing `select *`; it's a terrible practice.

Comment: Hi I know, it's just while I get it working, I would generally retrieve just the columns I need! Quicker than typing them all out at first...!

Comment: Sorry, am I putting the For loop within the function or in my code-behind in my event?

Comment: if I do that I get the error that 'dt' is not declared. I can see what I'm trying to do but I can't access that datatable!

Comment: In your event you should have: `Dim dt as DataTable = YourClass.AgencyDetails()` then you can access dt as this is what the `AgencyDetails` return.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to retrieve the data from the DataReader object, you should call the Read() method:

```
 While reader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", _
            reader(0), reader(1)))
    End While
```

This method moves the SqlDataReader to the next record.